# Add the attachment with image from static resource and value from text area field as pdf file

Tags: attachment, static-resources, blob.topdf

I generating the attachment from trigger action,
Need to generate the attachment as pdf file, contains image from static resource and value from text area field.
I have trying to use blob.toPdf() to convert the pdf,

I am able to generate the pdf file from text area, however not able to add image into pdf file.

Please find below code,

```
Blob body=[Select Name, ContentType, Body From StaticResource where name='resoursename'].body; 
Attachment attachmentPDF = new Attachment();
attachmentPdf.parentId = cse.id;
attachmentPdf.name = cse.name + '.pdf';
attachmentPdf.body = blob.toPDF('text area values');
insert attachmentPDF;
```

Could you please let me know  how to combine image and text area in single pdf file.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly compose a PDF from a text area and a blog image. Instead, they need to be "rendered" or "Printed" as a PDF in some kind of composition program or what some refer to as a "RIP" (the equivalent of Adobe Acrobat Exchange).

The only way I know of that you can do something like this from within Salesforce is to output the text area content into a VF page and also put the image on the page in an acceptable format such as JPG, PNG, Tiff, etc, then use `renderAs = PDF` and save the VF page to a file. Your only other alternative would be to use a 3rd party solution.